# How do I create a new object using strings and Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console

What I'm trying to do is make a banking application and at the beginning it would ask whether you want to create a savings or a current account and then asks you to enter a name for the one you selected. I'm trying to make the program create an object with a name that I've written down. It doesn't recognize the name that I've given them.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 's' if you want a savings account. Enter 
        'c' if you want current account.");

        string which = Console.ReadLine();

        if (which == "s")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Savingacc name;
            name = new Savingacc();
            name.mainmenu();                
        }
        else if (which == "c")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Currentacc name;
            name = new Currentacc();
            name.mainmenu();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code would not even compile.  What makes you think you can declare a string variable called `name`, then declare another variable called `name` of a completely different type right after?  What are the definitions of `Savingacc` and `Currentacc`?

Comment: Just say if it's not possible then, i'm just trying to find a way to have individual accounts.

Comment: Is that making a sense to write or perform the same action on either of these two conditions? And one more thing is, declaring a variable (i.e. name) inside the scope of if/else is useless in case if you want to use it outside of this scope.

Comment: @AlcoGoblin Anything is possible, you haven't included a [MCVE] so I have no idea what you currently have or how to fix it

Comment: You can´t do much with the objects that where created in the if/else-branch, as they exist only within those branches, but not in the surrounding code. Anyway it´s not clear to me what you mean by "doesn´t recognize the name".

Comment: This feels like exactly the type of question discussed here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/  The OP is clearly still learning the language

Comment: The classes themselves only have basic functions like deposit and withdrawal and like main menu thing to access those functions. nothing more.

Comment: @AlcoGoblin we still need to see the contents of those classes, please read how to include a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to make the variable name of the account the name they type in. You should make a property in the account class that contains the account name. Something along the lines of this very very basic example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var name = "Bob";
        var newAccount = new Account();
        newAccount.AccountName = name;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(newAccount.AccountName);
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the account class does not already have that?  OP did not provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

you have defined two different variables with same name, rename one of them.

```
    string which = Console.ReadLine();

    if (which == "s")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Savingacc savingAccountObj;
        savingAccountObj = new Savingacc();
        savingAccountObj.mainmenu();                
    }
    else if (which == "c")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Currentacc curAccountObj;
        curAccountObj = new Currentacc();
        curAccountObj.mainmenu();
    }
```

in **if** and **else** blocks, you've got the name of account from the user, but you haven't used it.

Comment: you have to variables which are named 'name' in one **Scope**. in one scope, you can not have two variables with same name.

Comment: Add this information to your answer, not the comments of your answer

Comment: @MehrdadTajdini `string name` declaration is on both statements, you can define `string name` out of the `if` scope (`string name;`) and assign the value inside the statements (`name = Console.ReadLine();`)